# Can the gerund be used after a form of "agree to" (e.g. "agrees to doing", "agree to going" and "agreed to leaving")?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

1. He agrees to *doing/do* her work because she helped him earlier.
2. I agree to *go/going* there.
3. I agreed to *leaving/leave* home earlier.

In my opinion, gerunds shall be used after "to (preposition)" in the above sentences because it seems appropriate according to the rule of putting verb+ing after preposition. However, I am not sure if gerunds will be used in the above sentences because people don't say "I agree to going there". **Is the usage of gerunds correct in the above sentences?**

Answer (score 1):

It's not a mortal sin, but the simple infinitive is more usual.

If you want to over-analyse a bit, when you use the gerund, you're agreeing to that action / activity “in general”, as acceptable, rather than specifically to take that action. For example:

> **I agree to go home** - *I will go home (now, or at a particular time that's been suggested)*
>
> **I agree to going home** - *I agree that going home would be a good idea. I'm not saying I will do it now or at any particular time*
>
> **I agree to hunting foxes** - *I'm a posh twit who thinks chasing animals until they're terrified and watching as they are horribly mangled by a group of ferocious hungry dogs is ok*
>
> **I agree to hunt foxes** - *I'm a posh twit who is going to go do those horrible things now*

... honestly just trying to find a good example, though I'm not keen on hunting :o)